# Magento 2 - WYSIWYG uploaded images resized to 500px wide. How can I prevent this?

Tags: magento2, cms-block, cms-pages, image-resizing

When uploading large images to be used within a block or page, **Magento 2** resizes them to **500px width**.
I don't want that instead I want them left at their original size.

I have no extensions installed apart from my theme which is **Ultimo**. Help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your settings in
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Images Upload Configuration?

Comment: Didn't even know that option existed. That was the problem. Many thanks